# Google Analytics API, as service, User unique identifier

Tags: google-analytics-api, google-oauth

I'm looking for a unique identifier for authorized users with oauth2, with scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly`.

Without google plus scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login`.

At [google document reference](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/accounts/list) i found `username` field. Description says.

> Email ID of the authenticated user

I'm wondering if this field is unique identifier or not.
Any knows anything about this?

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of a round about way of doing it but the Management API has a method called [accountSummeries.list](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/accountSummaries/list) it returns a list of google analytics accounts the current authenticated user has access to.

It also returns Username which is their email address.

> username string Email ID of the authenticated user

```
{
  "kind": "analytics#accountSummaries",
  "username": string,
  "totalResults": integer,
  "startIndex": integer,
  "itemsPerPage": integer,
  "previousLink": string,
  "nextLink": string,
  "items": [
    management.accountSummaries Resource
  ]
}
```

This is the only method I have found that just uses the google analytics API to get info about the user.  Alternative is to request profile or email scopes as well and then go though the people API.

*Note: You can also decrypt the token id returned by the authentication which will give you Googles internal unique user id.  This is a bit harder way of doing it though.*

Comment: id_token returned after auth is not useful unless profile scope is on. Anyway i had another issue with refresh_token which lead to this question. I fixed that one. google does not return refresh_token for an already authorized app which requests again for access_token. So i should keep the original data which has sent the first time. So my question has no value. with profile scope user id is accessible.

Comment: Still if you are already authenticating to google analytics you can access the Google Analytics management API and get their email that way.  You don't need additional scopes the data is there email address is part of account information returned.

Comment: @DaImTo So "username" is always the email address? Why does the docs describe it as "Email ID"?

Comment: Cant tell you why Google uses the words they do sorry.   In my experience it is always the users email address which may i fact be used as the primary key of an email making it the email id.